# curious gcc compiler code for x |= 128 when x is uint8

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization, cpu-registers

I've recently stumbled upon an interesting compiler code which I don't understand.
Take the following code:

```
unsigned char x;
...
x |= 127;
x |= 128;
```

For the first statement, the compiler generates:

```
or eax, 0x7f.
```

However, for the second statement, it becomes:

```
or eax, 0xffffff80
```

It seems that for values less than 127, one byte values are used whereas after 128 dword's are preferred.

Does anybody have any idea why this happens?
I reproduced this gcc 6.2 (latest I think).

I tried to post on the gcc mailing lists (gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org or gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org ) but I only got delivery failures.

Comment: I suspect that's just an artifact of how your disassembler formats numbers (`0x80` is negative if interpreted as a signed number).

Comment: I'm using gdb. Here's how it prints the values in the console https://pastebin.com/0A2SXUNU

Comment: I also compiled the code with -S and got this: https://pastebin.com/g8aSn9iy

Comment: If you compile with gcc -S, the generated .s file has `orl $-128, %eax`. For the mailing lists, usually the failures come with an explanation (typically, you tried to send html emails instead of pure text).

Comment: Both instructions perform a 32-bit "dword" sized OR operation, and both instructions are encoded with an 8-bit immediate operand that's sign extended to 32-bits.

Comment: The constants are signed, so as mentioned, are sign extended.  To make them unsigned, use 127u and 128u.

Comment: @JustinJ. Using 128U instead of 128 makes no difference, sign extension will be done nevertheless. You can try it out :)

Comment: @SterpuMihai: My compiler just gave "or eax,80h" either way.  I guess it is smart enough to know that the result is a byte so don't bother extending past 8 bits...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both instructions are 3 bytes wide as is apparent from the disassembly output:

```
 83 c8 7f                or     $0x7f,%eax
 83 c8 80                or     $0xffffff80,%eax
```

The 83 / 1 is [32-bit register / memory with 8-bit sign-extended immediate value](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/OR.html):

```
83 /1 ib    OR r/m32,imm8   r/m32 OR imm8 (sign-extended).
```

Thus in effect it *does* change the non-visible part of the 32-bit register, but it doesn't matter. It is not less efficient than any other method. There is also no instruction that would *not* sign-extend the 8-bit immediate value, except those that operate with 8-bit register halves/quarters. But using this instruction makes it work the same way with other registers that are addressable with `r/m32` but which cannot be accessed as individual bytes (edi, esi for example).

Comment: how did you generate the assembly instructions in that form?

Comment: compiled with `-c` into object file (I have 64-bit computer so I compiled with -m32); then viewed from the `.o` file with `objdump -d`

Comment: Ok so the good news is that the assembly code is good. But it would be interesting to see what is wrong with the way these are displayed.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, it's just a size optimization  by the compiler. Using `0x00000080` would require the longer 5 byte instruction.

Comment: @SterpuMihai nothing is wrong. 0x80 interpreted as 8 bit signed integer value is -128, which is equal to 0xFFFFFF80 when represented as 32 bit signed integer value. So the machine code is using the 8 bit form to store the value, the disassembler shows the extended 32 bit value which will be used by the `or` calculation itself, saving you some work in your head to convert 0x80 from 8 bits to 32 bits to fully understand the calculation. Upper 24b of `eax` will be damaged by it, but that does not matter, as `x` is `char`, so only lower 8 bit values are relevant.